# Tikz centering stops being inline

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to include a centered, inline Tikz figure in my LaTex document. If I just enter the TikZ code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
 ... 
\end{tikzcd}
```

the resulting figure shows up align *left*. I read that the way to fix this is to add "centering", as in:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzcd}
      ...
   \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
```

But then the TikZ figure shows up centered at the *top* of the page. How can I have it both ways: centered and inline?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *centered and inline*. Do you mean *displayed*? Try using `\[\begin{tikzcd}...\end{\tikzcd}\]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. But maybe you're looking for a *displayed* diagram, not an inline one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
This is the previous paragraph. Previous paragraph. Previous paragraph. Previous paragraph. Previous paragraph. Previous paragraph. 

This is an \emph{inline} diagram with 
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r]&B
\end{tikzcd}
in the middle. This is the rest of the paragraph. This is the rest of the paragraph. 

This is a \emph{displayed} diagram with
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r]&B
\end{tikzcd}
\]
centered on its own line.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure the distinction introduced by @SandyG is sound an his/her solution works and seems really suited when the TikZ content has a mathematical meaning.

Nevertheless some extra explanations could be useful.

To get *displayed* content, you should fist go in vertical mode and define a container, in the center of which the object will be centered.

The `float` that you tried with `figure` is an example, but as it is floating, it is positioned by LaTeX out of the text flow at a place that appears (to it) appropriate. When possible he will chose the tip of the next page, hence your result.

To get a in flow centering you need an other sointainer, eg

1)A paragraph

```
 {\centering <content>\par}
```

after a blank line or another`\par`.

2)The `center` environment:

```
\begin{center}
<content>
\end{center}
```

A `minipage`:

```
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
<content>
\end{minipage}
```

4. And so on.